# How can I use the values from a combobox in a click event method in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, combobox

So first, I am very new to programming and this is my first time posting so sorry in advance!

---

So I'm posting my updated code below and removed the previous information I posted to avoid confusion about what I'm asking since I realize now that I originally asked the wrong question.

I need the `ComboBox` selection to be accessible by the `PostBtn_Click`. Once I click the button, I need to take the value selected, and use it within my `CalculateWindChill()` method within my `Forecast` class. Most of my attempts have resulted in an error telling me that the name does not exist in the current context.

```
private void PostBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Forecast currentForecast = new Forecast();
        {
            predicted_LoTemp = 
            Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
            Wind_Speed = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

            HiTempLbl.Text = 
            Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
            LoTempLbl.Text = 
            Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
            WindSpeedLbl.Text = 
            Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

            WindChillLbl.Text = 
            Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
        }
    }       
    public class Forecast
    {
        public int Predicted_LoTemp { get; set; }
        public int Wind_Speed { get; set; }

        //Formula for calculating wind chill
        //Currently "Predicted_LoTemp" and "Wind_Speed" do not pull 
        //a value from the combobox as needed

        public double CalculateWindChill()
        {
            double WindChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * 
            Convert.ToDouble(Predicted_LoTemp) - 35.75 *
            Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(Wind_Speed), 0.16) + 
            0.4275 * Convert.ToDouble(Predicted_LoTemp) *
            Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(Wind_Speed), 0.16);

            return WindChill;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `ComboBox` should be irrelevant to this class of yours. The controls on a form are the responsibility of that form. The form gets input from the `ComboBox` and then sets an appropriate property on an instance of your class. That property should not know or care where the data came from.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for that information! So I see now that I can declare the SelectedItem from the instance of my class and not the class itself. How could I get that information to the class, though? For use in a formula within the class.

Comment: We don't know how you can get the data into the instance of your class because we don't know how you're using it. If the form containing the `ComboBox` is creating the instance then it can pass this data into it. If the two aren't directly related then it depends how they are indirectly related. Exactly what you should do depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve, which we don't know.

Comment: Got it. Sorry about that. I just added some more of my code to hopefully better explain what it is I'm trying to do. I really appreciate your help with this! Essentially I just need to access two selections from a combobox for use in my windchill formula.

Answer (score 0):

You should just make those `Forecast` properties regular auto-properties:

```cs
public class Forecast
{
    public int PredictedLoTemp { get; set; }
    public int WindSpeed { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var product = PredictedLoTemp * WindSpeed;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can then set them based on the `ComboBoxes` when you create the `Forecast` object:

```cs
var currentForecast = new Forecast
                      {
                          PredictedLoTemp = (int)PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem,
                          WindSpeed = (int)WindSpeed.SelectedItem
                      };

currentForecast.DoSomething();
```

You then use those same properties within the `Forecast` class.

EDIT:

Addressing your updated question. The issue is that you're not actually setting the properties anywhere. I provided you with an example above but you didn't follow it. Firstly, this is weird:

```cs
Forecast currentForecast = new Forecast();
{
    predicted_LoTemp = 
    Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
    Wind_Speed = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

    HiTempLbl.Text = 
    Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
    LoTempLbl.Text = 
    Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
    WindSpeedLbl.Text = 
    Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

    WindChillLbl.Text = 
    Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
}
```

I don't know why you have those braces there but I think that you might be confused about how object initialisers work. Those braces are completely pointless and that code should be written like this:

```cs
Forecast currentForecast = new Forecast();

predicted_LoTemp = Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
Wind_Speed = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

HiTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
LoTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
WindSpeedLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

WindChillLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
```

As you can see, you're not setting the properties of the `Forecast` object anywhere there so the data is not getting into the object to use. If you had followed the example I provided then you'd be doing this:

```cs
var currentForecast = new Forecast
                      {
                          Predicted_LoTemp = (int)PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem,
                          Wind_Speed = (int)WindSpeed.SelectedItem
                      };

predicted_LoTemp = Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
Wind_Speed = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

HiTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
LoTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
WindSpeedLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

WindChillLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
```

Notice that, in this case, there is no semicolon after the `Forecast` constructor so the braces are actually part of the object initialisation. That syntax is literally called an object initialiser. That code is equivalent to this:

```cs
var currentForecast = new Forecast();

currentForecast.Predicted_LoTemp = (int)PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem;
currentForecast.Wind_Speed = (int)WindSpeed.SelectedItem;

predicted_LoTemp = Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
Wind_Speed = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

HiTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
LoTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
WindSpeedLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

WindChillLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
```

Now you're actually setting the properties before using them.

The one other change is that you appear to want to treat the properties as `double` values, so you should probably declare them as `double` in the first place. I used `int` because you were already but if they will be treated as `double` then declare them as that type.

Comment: Ok, I've made those changes and my object is not recognizing the auto-properties assigned from the Forecast class. It is just saying that it "does not exist in the current context".

Comment: With the auto properties set as you recommended, shouldn't I be able to reference those directly from the instance of my class? Or is there some sort of "middle-man" I am missing to allow those to communicate? I assumed the instance could pull any information I put inside of its class.

Comment: @Dylan, your terminology is a bit all over the place but if you're saying that want to use those properties in a method in the `Forecast` object then yes, you can do that. If what you did is not working then you did it wrong. See my updated answer for an example of the sort of thing you should be doing. If there's still an issue, I suggest that you edit your question and add the new code so we can see what you're doing wrong and instruct you how to fix it.

Comment: I’ve updated my question and the contents to hopefully better explain what I’m trying to do. Sorry about the terminology being off, this is my first coding course so I just have to work on it.

Comment: @Dylan, I have updated my answer to address your updated question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of that information! I see where I went wrong with trying to implement your solution, but I do think I have a better understanding of object initializers now!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got it to work with the following:

```
 private void PostBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int LoTempSelection = Convert.ToInt32(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
       int WindSpeedSelection = Convert.ToInt32(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);

       Forecast currentForecast = new Forecast( LoTempSelection,  
       WindSpeedSelection);
        {
        HiTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedHiTemp.SelectedItem);
        LoTempLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(PredictedLoTemp.SelectedItem);
        WindSpeedLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(WindSpeed.SelectedItem);
        
        WindChillLbl.Text = 
        Convert.ToString(currentForecast.CalculateWindChill());
        }
    }

    public class Forecast
    {
        public int Predicted_LoTemp { get; set; }
        public int Wind_Speed { get; set; }

        public Forecast(int LoTempSelection, int WindSpeedSelection)
        {
            Predicted_LoTemp = LoTempSelection;
            Wind_Speed = WindSpeedSelection;
        }
```

Comment: If the `Forecast` object MUST have those properties set then it is appropriate to add a constructor that sets them. What you had still would have worked if you had set the properties though, as I had already demonstrated in my previous example. Just note that, now that you have that constructor, you can't create a `Forecast` object without providing those values. If that's OK then you're good to go. If it's not then you've created a new problem. In that case, you should either add another constructor without parameters or just set the properties when they need setting.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that info! In my case, they will always need those same 2 values, but I will keep that in mind for the future.